# My home made compost produces leachate which smells a bit and is mixed with soil underneath, can i use that soil?

Tags: compost, compost-tea

I've used a plastic bin with several holes done into it as a composting container. The content are all veggies and fruit leftover.

The compost gives out excess water (called leachate / compost tea). see [hotbin leachate](https://www.hotbincomposting.com/blog/what-is-compost-leachate.html)

I'm not sure about the color, but it does smell a bit, and that water gets absorbed by a large tub of soil beneath, which is compost collected from previous cycle, and is supposed to be used as a fertilizer.

Normally, we wait for that compost to dry up before using it, but is it harmful to use the wet compost mix with leachate already present.
Is drying it up enough in open air to let it be used as fertiliser, or we need to wash it up before using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the link you provided indicates, the compost materials being added are generally too wet and the excess water cannot be eliminated by the normal fermentation process. The result is an anaerobic fermentation (not enough air in the mix) which produces harmful substances rather than beneficial compost tea. As the documentation says, add dry materials to your wet compostables until the process runs correctly, without odours. To make use of the doubtful liquid you could consider diluting it 1:10 with water and using it on a grass plot. Good luck with your next batch of compost.